# Float 3 divs next to each other and stack on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, joomla3.0

I have searched the forum and tried numerous ways of doing this based on current answers but nothing seems to work how I need it to so any help is GREATLY appreciated as I am pulling my hair out!

I am working in Joomla 3 and have created a custom html module to display a download with sign up form.

I need to have some text on the left, the sign up module I am calling with Modules Anywhere in the center and an image on the right, so like this:

```
Text  |  Module  |  Image
```

And then on small screens it should stack so like this:

```
Text
Module
Image
```

The code I have which isn't working is:

```html
<div style="float: left;">Blah blah blah</div>
<div>{module Newsletter Signup}</div>
<div><img src="images/content/ebook.png" alt="ebook" width="150" /></div>
```

I would like to have the spacing as a percentage so it looks nice and even on all screen sizes when in horizontal view.

Thanks in advance for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a different layout at a certain breakpoint, you'll need CSS media queries:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    blah blah blah
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    {module}
  </div>
  <div class="col alignImgRight">
    <img src="images/content/ebook.png" alt="ebook" width="150" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row:after { clear: both; }

.row:before, .row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table; }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col { 
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333333%; }

  .alignImgRight { text-align: right; }
}
```

Of course you can change the breakpoint to whatever you want. In this situation the 1/3 width and float of the column will only apply above 768px screen width. Below that, the divs will take their default 100% width with no float (i.e. stacked). The `.row` parent element simply contains all the columns with a clear on it, so they don't all spill out and mess up layouts with the floats.

I would highly recommend look at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) as a responsive framework. It's an industry standard for handling layouts like this.

Comment: That's fantastic thanks so much. It works great, the only thing is I want the image on the right to be aligned to the right of that div, currently I think it is centered within the div, is that possible?

Comment: I've updated my answer for the image align. The image align will only apply to the non-stacked layout. If you want it always aligned to the right, just move the `.alignImgRight` bit of CSS out of the media query.

Comment: Just amazing, its perfect, thanks so much for taking the time to help ad thanks to everyone else who answered too. I will check out the bootstrap documentation :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this -> http://jsfiddle.net/tm4trhsw/

```css
#wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.item {
    float:left;
    width:27%;
    outline:1px solid blue;
    margin:0 0.5%;
    padding:2%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
    .item {
        float:none;
        width:100%;
        margin-bottom:5px
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="text" class="item">TEXT BLA BLA</div>
<div id="module" class="item">MODULE BLA BLA</div>
<div id="image" class="item">Image BLA BLA</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Floats can be tricky. You have a couple of other options:

**1. Display: inline-block and display: block**

At small screen sizes:

```
.text, .module, .image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then use a min-width media query from whatever width you want to have them sit side by side. The width you choose (here 700px) is whatever works for your design:

```
@media (min-width: 700px) { 
    .text, .module, .image {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 30%; /*you'll have to play with this % */
    }
 }
```

[Mozilla Developer Info on Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

**2. Flexbox**

Setup the parent container of the three sections to display as flex and the children to behave the way you want them.

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center; /*you might prefer space-between. It depends on how it looks*/
}
```

There are lots of options for flexbox if you're able to use it (that is, not supporting some jurassic browser). Try some generators - there are lots of good ones - and check out [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for a great explanation of flexbox. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table{
    width: 100%;        
    display: table;
}
.table-cell{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    width: 33.333%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #f7f7f7;
}
.table-cell:nth-child(1){
    border-left: none;   
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
    
    .table-cell{        
        width: 100%;  
         border-left: none;
         display: table-caption;
    }
    .table-cell:nth-child(1){
        border-left: none;        
    }
    .table-cell:nth-child(2){
      background: #ccc;     
      
    }
    
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-cell">Text</div>
     <div class="table-cell">Module</div>
     <div class="table-cell">Image</div>
</div>
```